# Regex issue with double plus ("++")

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python utility that compares Debian packages. The Python re module has a bug I think on regexes involving the string '++...' and possibly some other repeated characters.

- python 2.7.6
- Python regex module is not available on the systemin

This match fails

```
re.match("libstdc++", "time  1.7-23build1")
```

This match succeeds ( returns "none")

```
re.match("libstdc+", "time  1.7-23build1")
```

This match succeeds ( returns "none")

```
re.match("libstdc+\+", "time  1.7-23build1")
```

I could jump briefly into BASH or perl to do the match, or to add the backslash, but what about a Python workaround...

**Q: Is there a way in Python to do a string match or substitution without the re or regex modules?**

Comment: What makes you believe there is a "bug"? The first regex is invalid, the latter *doesn't* succeed/match, as expected.

Comment: `+` in regex means "repeat the last character/group one or more times", to match a literal `+` you need `"\\+"`.

Comment: re handles a single "+" character but not multiple. Could be a bug in documentation.. or I could be all wrong too. edit: I added an example of a single + succeeding.

Comment: @JohnP.Fisher That's wrong. Your pattern matches strings like `libstdc+`, `libstdcc+`, `libstdccc+`, `libstdccccccccccccc+`, etc. If you want to match `libstdc++` you have to use the pattern `libstdc\+\+`.

Comment: So User286 are you saying that the re module accepts only perl-like regex patterns as the first param and I have misunderstood the documentation ( a likely possibility I admit)

Comment: @JohnP.Fisher - What do you *think* the documentation said?

Comment: What do you mean the python regex module is not available on the "systemin"? If you can't use regexes, why are you... using regexes?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: There are 12 characters that must be escaped in regex if you want them to match: | \ { [ ) ( + ^ . $ ? and *

Comment: @Rob I had a complete brain fade and decided for some Friday reason that re.match was string matcher like the two methods you suggested rather than a real regex tool.

Comment: @Scott "systemin" is a typo, I am using my utility on systems shipped to customers, so adding more modules is non-trivial. I was trying to say " don't bother suggesting the regex module"

Comment: @Daniel I an comparing the output (Ubuntu systems)  of dpkg -l in various scenarios/systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Q: Is there a way in Python to do a string match or substitution without the re or regex modules?

Yes. For string match use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) (to find a match anywhere in the string) or [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) (to find a match at the beginning only):

```
In [5]: 'libstdc++' in 'time  1.7-23build1'
Out[5]: False

In [6]: 'time  1.7-23build1'.startswith('libstdc++')
Out[6]: False

In [8]: 'libstdc++' in "I really like libstdc++. It's cool."
Out[8]: True
```

For substitution, use `str.replace`:

```
In [10]: 'libstdc++ is awful'.replace('libstdc++', 'spinach')
Out[10]: 'spinach is awful'
```

One can also use a regular expression composed of literal characters. Of course, one needs to escape any character that has a special meaning to `re`:

```
In [7]: bool(re.search(r'libstdc\+\+', 'time  1.7-23build1'))
Out[7]: False

In [8]: bool(re.search(r'libstdc\+\+',"Alas, poor libstdc++! I knew him, Horatio"))
Out[8]: True
```

For the regular expression, notice the `r` at the beginning of the string and the backslashes which precede each `+`.  Each of these are explained in the Python [regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: You answer is absolutely correct, but it may be helpful to reiterate what was said in the comments as well: the OP's original regex would work just fine if he escaped the special characters: `'libstdc\+\+'`.

Comment: I took his **bold question** to imply that he didn't really want regular expression at all, and that `import re` was just the only hammer he had available.

Comment: @Rob that is exactly what I asked for. The docs suggest using 'in' instead of the string method. I see that I misunderstood the re documentation to say that I could put any string into its pattern parameter. The fact that you can't do that makes sense, now that I think about it.

Comment: I think he was only asking for a workaround because he couldn't get the regex to work and dismissed it as even being a viable option. I think there would still be some benefit to future readers to add the corrected regex for reference. Whether you do or not, you still get my upvote because your answer is exactly what was asked for.